# How to show dates instead of months in plots for a column with datetime type in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, python-datetime

I have a dataframe with column : Week and Spend.

For instance :

Week            Spend

2019-01-13       600

2018-12-30       400

The Week column is in datetime format.
When I create a line chart to see the trend, I get the plot with x axis labels as following:

[image]

I want the dates to be shown as is, instead of being aggregated as months. This is because I want to see the weekly change.

Comment: Looks like week is a datetime object, which will get aggregated on the x axis  so that you don't have so many labels.  If you format the column as a string prior to plotting it will no longer do that.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there is an alternative to that. Thanks so much !